# Filters in rga for Google Analytics API

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

What if I have at the end of my link this :

```
&filters=ga%3Avar!%40other
```

So, how I'm going to write this in code? I have tried with this:

```
filters = "ga: var!=40"
```

But got an error:

```
 Values must match the following regular expression: 'ga:.+'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URLdecode("ga%3Avar!%40other")` yields `"ga:var!@other"`. So I'd try `filters = "ga:var!@other"`.